# windows phone 7 Background Agent

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have one question related with new Mango future. I'v activate background agent. What heppe when I am reboot device? I should activate agent again or not? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The agent will still be running after a reboot. It will run for 14 days, so at least every 14:th day you have to refresh the scheduling of your background agent.

Comment: Cool thx. I know about 14 days. I was desturbed by rebooting.